# Angular: manage the style of items with the disabled attribute

Tags: angular

In an application (angular 10), I put some form fields with the attribute disabled.
Everything works well, however no style appears on the elements of type select, unlike the input type fields. See below:

[image]

I would like to recover the applied style (background) of the input on the select elements.
How can I do that properly?

Here’s my HTML code:

```
<div class="c-input"
     [ngClass]="{'error' : form.controls.birthDate.invalid && form.controls.birthDate.touched}">
  <input [attr.aria-label]="page + '.birthDate' | translate" [type]="isBrowserOldSafari() ? 'text' : 'date'"
         name="birthDate" id="birthDate"
         placeholder="{{ page + '.birthDate' | translate }} {{ isBrowserOldSafari() ? '(JJ/MM/AAAA)' : '' }}"
         [class.js-date-placeholder]="!isBrowserOldSafari()" required formControlName="birthDate">
  <label for="birthDate">{{ page + '.birthDate' | translate }} {{ isBrowserOldSafari() ? '(JJ/MM/AAAA)' : '' }}
    <span class="c-input__mandatory">*</span></label>
  <span
    class="c-input__error">{{ (birthDateError === "") ? ('error.required' | translate) : (birthDateError) }}</span>
</div>

   <!-- Profession -->
    <div class="c-input c-select"
         [ngClass]="{'error' : form.controls.profession.invalid && form.controls.profession.touched}">
      <select [attr.aria-label]="page + '.profession' | translate" required formControlName="profession">
        <option value="" selected>{{ page + '.profession' | translate }}<span class="c-input__mandatory">*</span>
        </option>
        <option *ngFor="let profession of professions"
                [value]="profession.identifiant">{{ profession.libelle }}</option>
      </select>
      <span class="c-input__error">{{ 'error.required' | translate }}</span>
    </div>

    <!-- Specialty -->
    <div class="c-input c-select"
         [ngClass]="{'error' : form.controls.specialty.invalid && form.controls.specialty.touched}"
         *ngIf="showSpecialtiesDropdown">
      <select [attr.aria-label]="page + '.specialty' | translate" required formControlName="specialty">
        <option value="" selected>{{ page + '.specialty' | translate }}<span class="c-input__mandatory">*</span>
        </option>
        <option *ngFor="let specialty of specialties"
                [value]="specialty.identifiant">{{ specialty.libelle }}</option>
      </select>
      <span class="c-input__error">{{ 'error.required' | translate }}</span>
    </div>
```

Here's the ts (the form):

```
  protected buildForm(): void {
    this.form = this.formBuilder.group({
      // birthdate
        birthDate: [{value: '', disabled: true}, [Validators.required]],
        // select
        profession: [{value: '', disabled: true}, [Validators.required]],
        specialty: [{value: '', disabled: true}, [Validators.required]],
  }
```

Thanks for help

Comment: You need to review what css class is applied to the input when is disabled and replicate the logic to the select element. Maybe is in c-input, I can see clearly with the code that you provide.

Comment: I imagine you can override the .css using `.c-input.c-select:disabled {background:silver;}`-the two selectors: "c-select" and "c-input" override any simple selector
`

Answer (score 1):

try something like this instead of disabled, in the components css,

```
 .filter__form select.ng-invalid { 
    /* first all selects will have gray color */
      color: rgb(170, 169, 169) !important;
    }
    .filter__form select option[value=""] {
      display: none;
    /*with this value which has "" will not be display in options*/
    }
    .filter__form select option {
      color: #000;
    /* with this all options will have black color when user selects one */
    }
```

you will get something like this:

[before user selects one](https://i.stack.imgur.com/na0bD.png): https://i.stack.imgur.com/na0bD.png

[and this when user selects one] [2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V3GfO.png): https://i.stack.imgur.com/V3GfO.png

i hope i understand the question

Comment: thanks @Eliseo: you solve my problem. How can I vote your answer ?